# bash re process a string before running

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, bash-expansion

consider there a directory called `hello world` in the current directory. Yes the directory has a space in it. For sake of example lets say it has a file called f1.txt.

```
ls 'hello world'
```

will print

```
f1.txt
```

but

```
a="ls 'hello world'"
$a
```

say

```
ls: cannot access ''\''hello': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'world'\''': No such file or directory
```

So the question is how to make ls list the directory `hello world`.
Basically how to this

```
a="1 2"
b="ls $a"
$b
```

to actually list the contents of the folder`hello world`

PS:
I don't want to do

```
a="1 2"
ls $a
```

I want to store it and only then run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
francois@zaphod:~$ mkdir "hello world"
francois@zaphod:~$ touch "hello world"/{a,b,c}
francois@zaphod:~$ a="ls 'hello world'"
francois@zaphod:~$ eval "$a"
a  b  c
francois@zaphod:~$
```

eval your variable will execute the variable as a text of the command you need to run